# Compare 2 differents array without looping PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-server, join

I'm wanting to know if there is any method to compare 2 array without loop, this code works but I would like to know if there is any method faster.

The reason I have done this with array is because I don't have achieve anything with PHP to join 2 different tables (different servers MySQL and SQL Server), let me know if you know anything about this.

I tried with `array_udiff()` but I didn’t get it.

Thanks

```
<?php
$array2 = [['PrNumber'=>'VID01','QTY'=>2],['PrNumber'=>'ANT','PK'=>123,'QTY'=>500],['PrNumber'=>'123','QTY'=>33]];
$array1 = [['PrNumber'=>'VID01','QTY'=>3],['PrNumber'=>'123','width'=>10.00]];
$products = array();
foreach($array2 as $row){
   if(array_search($row['PrNumber'], array_column($array1, 'PrNumber')) === false){
    array_push($products, $row);
   }
}
print_r($products);
```

Comment: @DaleK as I said, Im dealing with arrays because I didn’t get the way to make a join query of 2 tables in 2 differents servers (mysql and SQL Server), so if someone have an idea about this instead of the array initial inquiry, it will be better.

Comment: Is it a performance problem? because I believe if there is such function/method, that very function/method would use loops. You can just make you own code a function and call it a day.

Comment: @MSH Yes it is about performance. e.g.: in Python if you want better performances you must vectorize instead looping.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The goal is to match the values on both servers and get the values from server 1 that are not present in server 2.

Comment: Yes, this column is unique.

Answer (score 0):

To use `array_udiff`, one must supply a function for comparing the arrays. I've used your arrays in an example below:

```
<?php

$array2 = [
    [
        'PrNumber' => 'VID01',
        'QTY'      => 2,
    ],
    [
        'PrNumber' => 'ANT',
        'PK'       => 123,
        'QTY'      => 500,
    ],
    [
        'PrNumber' => '123',
        'QTY'      => 33,
    ],
];
$array1 = [
    [
        'PrNumber' => 'VID01',
        'QTY'      => 3,
    ],
    [
        'PrNumber' => '123',
        'width'    => 10.00,
    ],
];
function compareArrays($a, $b)
{
    return $a == $b;
}
array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'compareArrays');
```

You haven't said exactly what you're comparing in the two arrays or what result you're expecting. But this is a simple & efficient way of doing so that's built into PHP. If you need extra logic for your purposes, you can put that logic into the `compareArrays` function.

Comment: I would like to compare the [‘PrNumber’’] key if it matches in both arrays: unset from $array2.

Comment: Then you will have to use loops or modify the solution I gave you